# How to center rows?

Tags: html, css

I need to center these 2 rows in the middle like this. I am trying not to use flex. 
[image]

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjyxME

```
 <section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="square" id="square-1"></div>
    <div class="square" id="square-2"></div>
    <div class="square" id="square-3"></div>
    <div class="square" id="square-4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="square" id="square-5"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

>

```
.content {
    font-size: 0;
}

.square {
    height: 10rem;
    width: 118px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1rem 1.5%;
    background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: Just for clarification, the first row may be centered, but the second row is not. The square in the second row is aligned to the first column. That has nothing to do with centering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to define a width for the rows smaller than that of the container, in addition to using an automatic margin:

```
.row {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I've created a new CodePen showcasing that [**here**](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/qmKaXN).

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can center with

margin: 0 auto;

and the parent can have text-align: center;

[Center Like this](https://codepen.io/Zuriel/pen/RVJGVg)

```
.content {
font-size: 0;
}

.row {
  text-align:center;
}
.square {
    height: 10rem;
    width: 118px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1rem 1.5%;
    background: #000000;
}

   #square-5 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I want the last square to look like in the picture. I don't want the last square to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content {
    font-size: 0;
}

.row {
  text-align:center;
}
.square {
    height: 10rem;
    width: 118px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1rem 1.5%;
    background: #000000;
}

#square-5 {
  margin-left: -455px;
}
```

[Code pen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjyxME)